# If a right ideal ρ of ring R is minimal then ρ= eR for some idempotent e in R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In the artice [*A short proof of the Wedderburn-Artin theorem - Tsiu-Kwen Lee*], the author says:

> A right ideal $ρ$ of ring $R$ is minimal if and only if $ρ= eR$ for some idempotent $e\in R$ with $eRe$ is a division ring.

(Throughout ring $R$ is simple and associative but not necessarily with unity.)

I have question with the "only if" part.

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/706714/1233845), prove that the case $ρ^2=ρ$ is done, but in the case $ρ^2=0$ , how to find the idempotent $e\in R$？

Solution:

> Consider $Rρ \neq {0}$(since$ρ \neq {0}$) a two side ideal of $R$ ,then $Rρ=R$(by the simplicity),we have $Rρ^2=Rρ=R$ implies $ρ^2 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer inside the context of rings with identity because that is where most (all?) discussions of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem take place.

The claim

> A right ideal $ρ$ of ring $R$ is minimal if and only if $ρ= eR$ for some idempotent $e\in R$ with $eRe$ is a division ring.

is incorrect, even for rings with identity.

It should read

> If $\rho$ is a  minimal right ideal of a ring $R$, then either $\rho^2=\{0\}$ or $\rho$ is generated by an idempotent (and it additionally follows $eRe$ is a division ring where $eR=\rho$.)

Obviously when $\rho$ is nonzero and $\rho^2=\{0\}$ it is *impossible* to find an idempotent generator: it would have to satisfy $0\neq e=e^2=0$.

The context of the post you linked is "minimal right ideal *of a simple ring*".  In a simple ring, the case $\rho^2=\{0\}$ doesn't happen except when $\rho=\{0\}$ already.  Obviously this also is true more generally for semiprime rings, of which the semisimple rings of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem are examples.

It is also not true, in general that "$eRe$ a division ring implies $eR$ is simple."

As a counterexample, consider $R=\begin{bmatrix}F&F\\ 0&F\end{bmatrix}$ with the idempotent $e=\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

There simply has to be more constraints on $R$ to make these things true.

I suspect the paper you're reading from is only concerned with semiprime rings, and in that case the following existing answers cover both directions:

[$\impliedby$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1540487/29335)

[$\implies$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/706714/29335)

Comment: Does the "if" part of my claim also incorrect?

Comment: And why in the simple ring,  $ρ^2={0}$ only when  $ρ={0}$ ?

Comment: @Lee A simple ring is prime, so the annihilator of any nonzero right ideal is $\{0\}$.  Or you can say a simple ring is semiprime, and the definition of a semiprime ring is that it does not have nonzero nilpotent right ideals...

Comment: If $eRe$ is a division ring, it does not necessarily follow that $eR$ is simple.  Consider $R=\begin{bmatrix}F&F\\ 0&F\end{bmatrix}$ with the idempotent $e=\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: But if the simple ring $R$ does not have the unity, we can't say that $R$ is always prime.

Comment: And what does the $F$ mean in your new response?

Comment: @Lee Any field.

Comment: @Lee My answer is in the context of rings with identity, along with 99.99% of all discussions of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In fact,in the artice *[A short proof of the Wedderburn-Artin theorem - Tsiu-Kwen Lee]*, the author says that the prove works for rings that are not necessarily unital.(I will try hard to solve that.)

Comment: I think i'll take a look at this article too.

Comment: @Lee The claim in the article about it working for rings without identity is at least partially incorrect. $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is clearly a simple Artinian ring without identity, but it is also clearly not a matrix ring over a field.  Notice that in claiming that a simple right artinian ring $R$ is isomorphic to a matrix ring over a division ring, that would be implying that it *does* have an identity.  I notice the author is also not careful in explaining the $1$ in the computations. Perhaps it can be worked around (e.g. $(1-e)g=e-eg$) but the foregoing observations do not bode well.

Comment: I also feel something weird in this article.The identity is NOT necessarily exist, but as you say the $(1-e)g$ appears in the prove.And in the last page ,the article show that 1(identity) actually in the ring $R$.

Comment: @Lee I satisfied myself that the only substantial omission was to exclude the case $R^2=\{0\}$  If $R^2\neq 0$, which would amount to $R^2=R$ for a simple ring, then all of the arguments hold. The arguments carelessly using "1" where "1" is not defined all still work if you use the products (e.g. $e-ge$ for "(1-g)e".  The last sketchy point I thought was that $eR=R$ for $R$ simple implies $e$ is an identity for $R$. My solution was to note that the left annihilator $\ell (eR)=\ell R$ is a two-sided ideal, and it has to be zero, and that implies $r=re$ for all $r$.

Comment: So it does appear that a simple right Artinian ring $R$, with $R^2\neq \{0\}$, has an identity, and indeed is a matrix ring over a division ring.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right.